# increase the text size but keep the position of input field constant

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have an input field and I make its `height:25px`. If I increase the font-size inside that text field, although the box size is constant, it appears as it I added a whole lot of padding. When the font size is normal, it looks something like this:

**BEFORE**

[image]

But now when I increase the size of the font, it looks something like extra padding added something this:

**AFTER**

[image]

However, the padding is unchanged when I debug. I tried adding the box-sizing:border-box, but still it is unchanged. I would really appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks.

A simple demonstration can be achieved by just changing the size of the font-size.

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="HI"/>
    <input type="text" value="HELLO" style="font-size: 900px; height: 30px; width: 100%;"/>
    <input type="text" value="HI"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the example you provided, using Firefox 48.0a2.

Comment: Can you produce this issue with a snippet or bin?

Comment: you need to use vertical-align:middle; so no matter the font-size/line-height, they can be align from middle

Comment: width:100% kills your demonstration ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the `vertical-align` propertie .

Defaut is `baseline` , `line- height` is equal to `font-size` if not reset.

example with `vertical-align`: *(added text and reduced some value from your funny example ;) )*

```css
input {
  vertical-align:middle;
  }

/* see div middle center. Notice: the tallest input gives the line-height on the line it stands */
div {
  background:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%) ,linear-gradient(to left,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 50%);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" value="HI"/> text
    <input type="text" value="HELLO" style="font-size: 90px; height: 30px; width:50px;"/> text
    <input type="text" value="HI"/>
  </div>
```